# How to update dependencies inside of third-party libraries without using as a module?

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

When we use a **third-party library** in our project , this **third-party library** may have used an old *dependencies* in its project, that can cause errors or bugs in our project. How can we force that **third-party library** to use an updated version of the dependency that does not conflict with our dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude a module from a third-party library and include a newer version of the same in the project.

Use `exclude` to remove the module included with the library.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display-ktx:20.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'io.grpc', module: 'grpc-okhttp' // removing grpc-okhttp included with the library
    }

    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.40.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an .AAR file then connect to the concern developer to replace the dependencies with newer one.